# count value per month based on conditions in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a table of **Purchases** that looks like this:

```
Chassis_Number  Customer_Trn  Purchase_ID  date_sold  selling_price  tax_amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234            567           1234567      2012-1-23  2345653        12343
2345            678           2345678      2013-4-05  1089255        11332
```

and another table **Credit_Customer** that looks like this:

```
Customer_Trn  Repayment  Monthly_Payment
----------------------------------------
567           456530     4530
```

I am trying to create a transaction that counts credit_customer purchases with respect to month(date_sold)

if credit_customer purchases<12/month then allow insert else rollback

```
Begin Transaction CC_Limit

    Alter Table Purchases
    ADD mon int

    Update Purchases
    Set mon = MONTH(date_sold)
    Where mon IS NULL

    Select Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn, Purchases.date_sold
    From Credit_Customer
    Inner Join Purchases
    On Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn=Purchases.Customer_Trn
    Order By Credit_Customer


    Declare @count int = (Select Count(*) from Credit_Customer)
    If @count<100

    Insert into Purchases (Chassis_Number,Customer_Trn,Purchase_ID,date_sold,selling_price,tax_amount)
        Values (@Chassis_Number,@Customer_Trn,@Purchase_ID,@date_sold,@selling_price,@tax_amount)


    Begin
    ROLLBACK trans
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i use transactions to accomplish the business rule:
credit purchases should not exceed 12 per month

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: the code is not working as intended; rollback should occur to prevent more than 12 vehicles purchased on credit for a particular month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the credit worthiness, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCreditWorthiness 
    @Customer_Trn int 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE isCreditWorthy bit = 0
    DECLARE @Yr = YEAR(getdate())
    DECLARE @Mon = MONTH(getdate())

    SELECT @isCreditWorthy = CASE WHEN COUNT(Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn) < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM Credit_Customer 
        INNER JOIN Purchases On Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn=Purchases.Customer_Trn 
    WHERE Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn = @Customer_Trn 
        AND MONTH(date_sold) = @Mon and YEAR(date_sold) = @Yr    

    RETURN @isCreditWorthy
END
```

Comment: this answer was useful... now do i write another sp and place the transaction block there or can i just place the transaction block immediately after?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this if you want to get all customers who have less than 12 transactions in a month:

```sql
SELECT Credit_Customer, COUNT(Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn) AS Cnt, YEAR(Purchases.date_sold) AS Yr, MONTH(Purchases.date_sold) AS Mon
FROM Credit_Customer 
Inner Join Purchases On Credit_Customer.Customer_Trn=Purchases.Customer_Trn 
GROUP BY Yr, Mon
HAVING COUNT(*) < 12
ORDER BY Credit_Customer
```

Comment: i am selling vehicles. I don't want to be selling all my vehicles on credit. There must be a limit as to how much vehicles i sell on credit.
i want to put that limit in with respect to month. rollback should occur to prevent more than 12 vehicles purchased on credit for a particular month.

Comment: I would write another stored procedure and have your application call it to check credit worthiness.  You can have another check and prevent the insert but the front end should handle this.

Comment: i am a begininger at coding SPs and TRANs... i place the code about in a if statement and it did not work. is it possible to use if with the above code? how?